# cordova-camera-roll plugin return only few images (not all the photos)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I build ionic 1 app and I'm trying to use plugin cordova-camera-roll
[cordova-camera-roll](https://github.com/bamlab/cordova-camera-roll)

and get all the photos, but it shows me only few photos instead all of them. e.g I have on my device 100 photos and it return me only 2 photos and it not throw any error.

my code

```
    CameraRoll.getPhotos(function(photo) {

}, function(err) {
}, {
  count: 12, // Optional, will only return the last N photos.
});

CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(base64String, function() {
}, function(err) {
});
```

so i'm looking a way to use infinite scroll.

in addition, the default directory it shows me the whatsapp photos first and not the photos taken by the camera.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the relevant code. Thanks.

Comment: What version of plugin are you using? Are you saving camera roll on external storage instead of device memory?

Comment: the same version of it https://github.com/bamlab/cordova-camera-roll. I save the camera roll in device memory